# docx4j - Why does saving to OutputStream return gibberish values?

Tags: ms-word, docx4j

I'm trying to create a Word document from a POJO using variable replace. I followed the tutorial listed at the bottom, but I'm seeing gibberish values in the OutputStream, i.e.

```
WordprocessingMLPackage.save(outputStream)
```

returns unreadable characters (black or empty boxes, diamonds, etc.)

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: https://rieckpil.de/howto-generate-documents-from-word-templates-with-docx4j-on-wildfly-14/

Comment: Sounds like you are mangling the character encoding at some point.  If you save the stream, is it a valid zip file?  If you can unzip it, what does you word/document.xml contain?

Comment: @JasonPlutext If I just save it, it writes to the desired output file (it's not zipped though). But I'm now facing a variable split issue -- given a docx template, what is the best way to convert some data from a POJO to said template (complete with tables and graphs)?